# PHP/MySQL multiple values in same column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a page where my users can paste in multiple item #s for that product and it will give them the parent model # for that particular item, where items are given individual identifiers.

However, my users paste there information into the textboxs, but it doesn't pull anything up. When I had one value to search it was able to find the items. My table structure is very simple.`Fcsku varchar(45), fnsku varchar(45), updated time(45` are not important to this function).

Here is my query **Updated**:

```
<form action="" method="get">  
  Paste your ZZZ's here: <br><input type="text" name="item" id="textbox"/><br>
  <input type="text" name="item2" id="textbox2"/>
  <script>document.getElementById('textbox').focus()</script><br />  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>  
</form>  
<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['item'])) {
    $item = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['item']);
    $item2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['item2']);     

    $sql = "select * from oak3_zzz_to_boo WHERE fcsku like '%".$item."%' or fcsku like '%".$item2."%'"; 
    $r_query = mysql_query($sql); 


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)) {  
        echo "<font color=red size=7>";
        echo '<center><br /> Parent ASIN: '.$row['fnsku']; 
        echo "</center></font>";
        echo "<br><br><br><br><br>";
    }    
}
?>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: It does not pull any information when I try to have both of the multiple search boxes.

Comment: Or even if it could be one box, and it would search depending on how many seperate values were pasted would work for our purpose.

Comment: With updated code it appears to be working now! THANKS EVERYONE! But, would there be a way to search depending on how many seperate values were pasted into a single box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked at my server:

```
<form action="" method="post">  
    Paste your ZZZ's here:<br />
    <input type="text" name="item" id="textbox" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="item2" id="textbox2"/><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
    <script>document.getElementById('textbox').focus()</script>  
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $item = mysql_real_escape_string('%'.$_POST['item'].'%');
    $item2 = mysql_real_escape_string('%'.$_POST['item2'].'%');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM oak3_zzz_to_boo WHERE fcsku LIKE '" . $item . "' OR fcsku LIKE '" . $item2 . "'";
    $r_query = mysql_query($sql); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_query)) {  
        echo "<font color=red size=7>";
        echo '<center><br />Parent ASIN: ' . $row['fnsku']; 
        echo "</center></font>";
        echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />";
    }  
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have made the adjustment right before you commented. I have it now showing data from item, but not item2. I think it may be related to <?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['item'])){

$item = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['item']);
$item2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['item2']);

Comment: With updated code it appears to be working now! THANKS EVERYONE! But, would there be a way to search depending on how many seperate values were pasted into a single box?

Comment: @Spartacus38 - Ah, good. I cleaned the code a bit. Guessing you don't need it now tho. Please accept my answer. If you have another problem (after Googling and trying), post a new question :)